# How to add title, action buttons in ionic push notification

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm implementing push notifications using ionic framework. I'm following [sending push](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push) example given by ionic documentation. According to that the send request should be like

```
{
  "tokens":[
    "b284a6f7545368d2d3f753263e3e2f2b7795be5263ed7c95017f628730edeaad",
    "d609f7cba82fdd0a568d5ada649cddc5ebb65f08e7fc72599d8d47390bfc0f20"
  ],
  "notification":{
    "alert":"Hello World!",
    "ios":{
      "badge":1,
      "sound":"ping.aiff",
      "expiry": 1423238641,
      "priority": 10,
      "contentAvailable": true,
      "payload":{
        "key1":"value",
        "key2":"value"
      }
    },
    "android":{
      "collapseKey":"foo",
      "delayWhileIdle":true,
      "timeToLive":300,
      "payload":{
        "key1":"value",
        "key2":"value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want ios notification to have title, body and action buttons like

```
"alert" : {
     "body" : "This is a message from server",
     "action-loc-key" : "VIEW",
     "action" : [
        {
           "id" : "buttonTapped",
           "title" : "View"
        }
     ]
  }
```

Is it possible with ionic push notification service? Any help please or any other APIs which does that?

Comment: Yes, adding title is possible. Kindly take a look at the link attached.http://docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push#section-phonegap-push-plugin-options

Comment: are you using any plugin for handling notification ? and are you using FCM ?